# Convertir texto en parte de una imagen

Tags: javascript, html5

tengo una consulta... estoy haciendo un trabajo donde me piden que cree un numero de serial sobre un voucher de descuento. Esa parte ya esta resuelta, el problema viene cuando los quiero descargar. En la teoria se deberia poder descargar la imagen ya prediseñada (.jpg) junto con el codigo de descuento. Pero al ser dos elementos separados cuando descargo la imagen lo hace sin el correspondiente codigo. Hay alguna herramienta que pueda usar para "convertir" y "unificar" ese texto con la imagen asi al momento de la descarga lo hacen juntos? Habia pensado en poner un boton de compartir o de descarga pero creo que estaria en la misma posicion. Desde ya muchas gracias!

dejo el codigo para si alguno le sirve como lo hice o si tiene algun consejo para mejorarlo...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <img src="voucher.jpg" alt="imagen">
    </div>
    
    <script>

        var consulta = parseInt(prompt("Ultimo serial entregado?"));
        var letra = "MT00";
        var resultado = letra + consulta;
        var contador = [];
        var inicio = 0;

        for (i = inicio; i <= 1000; i++) {
            if (consulta <= 1000) {
                contador++;
                document.write("<p class= 'codigo'>Codigo de descuento: " + letra + (consulta + 1) + "</p>");
                break;
            } else {
                alert("Ya supero la cantidad de vouchers");
                break;
            }
        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si sabes PHP aquí está la solución a tu problema https://parzibyte.me/blog/2020/10/11/agregar-texto-imagen-php/

Comment: ... Y si no aquí está el manual sobre el tratamiento de imágenes con Javascript que podría darte luces https://desarrolloweb.com/manuales/19

Comment: Lo otro sería dibujar todo lo que planteas en una página web totalmente limpia y lista para enviarla a la opción de impresión del navegador... internamente en dicha página llamas a la función ```window.print()``` y te abrirá la opción de imprimir de forma automática, con esta opción de impresión puedes guardarla también en PDF